# Create a list of arn from data source "aws_iam_arn" output result in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use `data source "aws_iam_arn"` to retrieve user arns and assemble them to a local variables (a list) so it can be used to provision other aws resources. However I am stuck at pick the arn in the returned result
Here is my code

```
data "aws_iam_user" "this" {
  for_each  = { for user in local.users : user => user }
  user_name = each.value
}

locals {
  arn_list = [for user in data.aws_iam_user.this[*].arn : user]
  users = ["user1", "user2"]
}

output "data_result" {
  value = data.aws_iam_user.this[*]
}

output "user_arn" {
  value = local.arn_list
}
```

---

the output data_result showing something as below

```
+ data_result = [
      + {
          + user1   = {
              + arn                  = "arn:aws:iam::zzzzzzzzzz:user/user1"
              + id                   = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
              + path                 = "/"
              + permissions_boundary = ""
              + tags                 = {
                  + AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = "user1"
                }
              + user_id              = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
              + user_name            = "user1"
            }
          + user2 = {
              + arn                  = "arn:aws:iam::zzzzzzzzzz:user/user2"
              + id                   = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
              + path                 = "/"
              + permissions_boundary = ""
              + tags                 = {}
              + user_id              = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
              + user_name            = "user2"
            }
        },
    ]
```

I tried to access the arn using below

```
locals {
  arn_list = [for user in data.aws_iam_user.this[*].arn : user]
  users = ["user1", "user2"]
}
output "user_arn" {
  value = local.arn_list
}
```

but get error
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 11, in locals:
│   11:   arn_list = [for user in data.aws_iam_user.this[0].arn : user]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_iam_user.this is object with 2 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An
│ object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric
│ index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. You can use, for example:

```
arn_list = [for user in local.users: data.aws_iam_user.this[user].arn]
```

or simpler (but order can be different then in `local.users`):

```
arn_list = values(data.aws_iam_user.this)[*].arn
```